# Unable to update database row in PHP with $_POST variable

Tags: php, mysql

I want it so that when the user types into the textarea/input and clicks save changes, the information they input has been added and saved into the database. Below is my code:

```
$name = $_SESSION['u_name'];
$uid = $_SESSION['u_uid'];
$id = $_SESSION['u_id'];

$con = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "pass123", "db_name");

if ($con->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
    echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('connection failed. try again');</script>";
}

$remind1 = $_POST['remind1'];
$remind2 = $_POST['remind2'];
$remind3 = $_POST['remind3'];
$remind4 = $_POST['remind4'];
$remind5 = $_POST['remind5'];

if (isset($_POST['updBtn'])){
    $sql = "UPDATE reminders SET remindone='$remind1' WHERE username='$uid'";

    if ($con->query($sql) === TRUE) {
        echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('Updated successfully');</script>";
    }else{
        echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('error while updating. try again');</script>";
    }
}
```

Below is the corresponding HTML:

```
<form action="body.php" method="post"> 
    <input type="submit" class="sideBtn" value="Save Changes" name="updBtn"><br>       
    <input type="text" class="event" name="remind1"><br>
    <input type="text" class="event" name="remind2"><br>
    <input type="text" class="event" name="remind3"><br>
    <textarea class="event" name="remind4"></textarea><br>
    <textarea class="event" name="remind5"></textarea><br>
</form>
```

Ideally what would happen, is that whatever the user types into the textarea/input is updated in the database, then they can access and later tweak the text if they need to.

I have been able to pinpoint that my problem is somewhere along the $_POST variables in my PHP as, if I were to substitute the aforementioned variable with a string as such:

```
$sql = "UPDATE reminders SET remindone='hello' WHERE username='$uid'";
```

...it works perfectly. But with when using the POST variable, it does not work.

How can I fix this mistake of mine and make it so that the user is able to post text into the database? Is the $_POST variable required here or is there another method to achieve this?

Comment: what is the file name of your php code?

Comment: have you checked the php error log? Also - this code is vulnerable to sql injection, try with prepared statements instead

Comment: get rid of the repeating ids in html: `id="event"` - they should be unique. Or just remove them if not needed. (I doubt this will solve your problem, though)

Comment: the php file is contained in the html file. it is called body.php

Comment: What exactly isn't working? `echo` out your `$sql` and run it in phpMyAdmin or something else to make sure your query is correct.

Comment: the query itself works well, but when I incorporate the variables $remind1, $remind2, $remind3, and so on, the database is not updated with the contents of the variables.